# How to limit the insert operation of Mysql table where a fr_key count is <4

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to insert rows in my `CONTACT` table where i have a condition, when broadCastId (foreign_key) have `< 4` insertion happen. here i want when it become `>=4` not insert values in table. can any one give me the Solution of this..here i am using MySQL Database.
and i use a Query
`insert into neron_gui.BroadCastContact values(33,'Hello','8989898989',6) select count(*) from neron_gui.BroadCastContact where broadCastId=6;` which gives me error .
 Thanks in advance.

```
contactId| contactName| contactNumber| broadCastId
28       | sushil     |9876543210    | 5
29       | sonu       |9876543210    | 5
30       | sumu       |9876543210    | 6
31       | Anjal      |9876543210    | 6
32       | laxmi      |9876543210    | 6
```

Comment: could you share the insert command that is not doing what you expect?

Comment: just filter out those elements before preparing your query, either your data variable if in code, or adding this criteria in your selection if data comes from the SQL query itself

Comment: Do you want to stop inserting data in this table after it reaches broadCastId >=4 or you just want only values inserted into datatable which are not broadCastId>=4, it can insert values after it reaches the condition but with the specified criteria

Comment: You should use a subquery to see which values you want to include, then do a left join so all other values will get a null value

Comment: You have two tables contact and another one is?

Comment: Sory Dear i want to insert Query where `broadCastId` count <4

Comment: and i have only one table at this time

Comment: Can you show the `INSERT` query that is not working?

Comment: `insert into neron_gui.BroadCastContact values(33,'Hello','8989898989',6)
select count(*) from neron_gui.BroadCastContact where broadCastId=6;`

Comment: You should add that query to your question, along with what you expect it to be doing.

Comment: now i am update Query with my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could use a Trigger like this:**

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON contact
       FOR EACH ROW 
       BEGIN
         // -- THIS CONDITION (>=4) IN ELSE CLAUSULE --
         IF contact.broadCastId < 4 THEN
           {CLAUSULE_INSERT_INTO_CONTACT}
         ELSE
           {OTHER_OPERATIONS}{...statements to execute when condition is FALSE...}
         END IF;
       END;//

delimiter;
```